# Implement SSL in java without certificates

Tags: java, networking, ssl, secret-key, symmetric-key

Is it possible to implement SSL encryption by using pre-distributed keys (secret keys) in Java? If at all possible, I want to avoid certificates.

This should work, as certs are used for authenticating site validity. Am I correct or wrong in thinking this?

Thanks,
~Kyte

Comment: There is no SSL without at least one certificate.

Comment: TLS allows for pre-shared secrets, however - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK